# Verification of my employment has ended with other employer

Tags: job-offer, united-states, background-check

in the process of signing conditional offer letter. New employer want to verify that i am not working for any other employer. how do I prove since I am planning to put two weeks notice only after background check is completed?
Can new employer contact last employer after joining?

Location : USA

Comment: Questions like this always benefit from knowing your location.

Comment: Have you told them that you are currently employed?

Comment: Yes. I told them i am currently employed,

Comment: You indicated that the location is USA. So, your situation is interesting because in the US, usually, companies do not require you to prove that you are no longer working for any other employers as a condition for them to offer you a new job.

Answer (score 9):

"New employer want to verify that i am not working for any other employer."

This is an unreasonable thing for them to want, as you obviously *are* currently working for another employer.

Just tell your new employer that you don't want them talking to your old employer until after you have given notice.

And remind them that you plan to give notice only after you have a signed offer for your new job.

If, after joining, your new employer remains skeptical that you truly have quit your old job, they can always call your previous employer. In the U.S.A. it is common for a company to call another to verify the employment dates of an individual.

Comment: it's a part of pre-employment check. i guess I can ask them not to contact current employer during background check. Will new employer still reach out to last employer to verify employment end date after starting new job?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing this correctly.  Don't quit your current job until you have a signed and counter-signed offer letter from the new company in hand.  You also don't want your current employer to get wind that you're looking for a new job until you hand in your resignation.

Say to the new employer that you are currently employed, but you will be quitting your current job when you have the offer details worked out and everything is signed properly.  They are free to contact any of your other employers prior to your current one as they wish, but they are expressly prohibited from contacting your current employer until after the offer is submitted and signed; they may make the offer conditional on receiving appropriate feedback from your current employer vis a vis dates worked, confirmation you've quit your job after the fact, etc. if they like, this is a reasonable ask for them to make.  If they do not accept these terms, then better to not take this offer; you don't want to quit your current job, then they cancel this one, then you're out of a job.

Answer (score 2):

This company has a dumb approach.  I'm going to guess that you're probably working remotely and they're trying to prevent you from double-dipping.

There's really no way for employer A to prove that you're no longer working for employer B without A (or a designee) directly contacting B.  However, doing so may cause you undue stress in your ongoing situation with B.  If you'd actually quit working for B already, this would not be unreasonable.  Now, they want smart employees but no smart person is going to risk their livelihood in such a way.

Don't budge on any such thing until you have a signed offer letter where this is not a precondition.  What this IS telling you is that you would be starting a job in an environment of mistrust.  These kinds of situations don't usually improve - it's company culture.  You might want to pass on the opportunity and move on as a result.

Comment: you may be right. it's a remote position and company wants to make sure that you're not doing two full time jobs so that's why they want to verify end of employment with last employer. I am not sure if they want to verify as a part of pre-employment check or verify it once starting a new position. I haven't signed offer letter yet.  I've asked HR to clarify on this condition on how they will verify end of employment with last employer.

Comment: +1 for "environment of mistrust". I forgot to bring that up in my answer.