# current employer issue in background check

Tags: united-states, background-check

In the process of pre-employment check. During interview, I didn't mention in my resume about my current employer company B which I joined 5 months ago. instead, I told them that my current employer company A which I've been working with since 2016. in reality, I resigned from company A to join company B.

I am concern about background check. Shall I provide info about my new employer company B in background check since I never revealed about it during interview.

Will Background check agency identify end date with company A even if I list company A as current employer and select "Not to contact current employer"?

Comment: Did you outright lie to the prospective employer or did you just imply this via an outdated resume?

Comment: I lied because I didn't want reveal job that i started just few months back.

Comment: Have you given Company A as your reference?

Comment: no. I haven't given company A as my reference but I am planning to give it as a reference.

Comment: I'm confused, in your last question asked yesterday https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182074/verification-of-my-employment-has-ended-with-other-employer yesterday you replied in comments that "Yes. I told them i am currently employed, – SqlDBA  yesterday"

Comment: That's right. I told them that I am still currently employed company A which I left in July 2021.

Answer (score 12):

You have a BIG problem.

Background checks typically verify employment dates and job titles. So it's likely that your little ruse will blow up in your face.

Best you can do at this point is to come clean to your new employer, apologize profusely and assure them that it will never happen again. Then hope for the best.

Sorry, but if it were me, I'd immediately rescind the offer and blacklist you. Mistakes and problems can easily be worked and forgiven, but lying is a non-starter for me.

Maybe this can be a lesson for the future for you.

Answer (score 7):

> I am concern about background check. Shall I provide info about my new employer company B in background check since I never revealed about it during interview.

You should have mentioned that before in the process, or during interviews. This is something that will surely come up in a BG check.

Yes, you should provide them with this information ASAP if you want to minimize any consequences this could/will have.

> Will Background check agency identify end date with company A even if I list company A as current employer and select "Not to contact current employer"?

I suggest you don't do that. Listing it that way would be a plain lie.

Comment: I agree. I made a mistake by hiding my current employer. I don't think i can provide this info in this last stage. Is there an option to complete background check ? Do HR usually compare background check completion report with resume info?

Comment: @SqlDBA - in my experience, resume info is used as the basis of a background check. As DarkCygnus says, the least bad way to deal with this is let them know as soon as possible. If they choose not to employ you that is still much better than being fired when they discover the lie after you start work there.

Answer (score 1):

The BEST case scenario is that it would come out in a background check, and not after 5 years of employment with the company, when you will be quickly terminated for fraud.

Come clean IMMEDIATELY, you don't want to get hired and have this hanging over your head, and never do it again

Comment: Interesting answer, if OP truthly and accurately completes the background check process on what basis would there be fraud?  CVs are a summary of experience, people can make mistakes in interviews but the bit that is formally relied upon is normally the background check (at least in jurisdictions I've worked in).

Comment: That's what I would like to know. how do I complete the background check without getting caught? I can put my current employer info and let background check agency verifies it. Do HR actually compare background check completion report with resume info and do HR provide background check result to hiring manager?

Comment: They don't need to contact your employer to find payroll history

Comment: I have heard about situations were people have been fired for lying about degrees which they didn't have (famously Scott Thompson, ex-CEO of Yahoo). But a few month employment discrepancy discovered after FIVE years after the fact? I doubt any employer would be compelled to fire someone for that who was otherwise an employee in good  standing.

Comment: @teego1967 And what if a former ccoworker from comapny "B" shows up.  I've ended up coming accross either former coworkers or people who know them from as far as 30 years back, in entirely different industries and entirely different jobs.  If you tell the truth, you don't have to remember the lies

Comment: @teego1967 an ex coworker of a family member was fired for putting incorrect start/end dates on his job history to hide a job.  It only came out because the person was a trouble maker and they were looking at him more closely; but finding an automatic firing event made getting rid of them much easier.

Comment: What if I just put all correct info for background check including my current employer? that will help for background check without any red flag. However, Do HR inform hiring manager about discrepancy in employment history between BC report and resume?

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight, well then it's not *exactly* an "automatic" firing event, right? It's a pretext.

Comment: @teego1967 Even if they'd been an employee in good standing, they'd've been immediately sacked for the same issue if HR had found out.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight, I don't believe it. The whole reason they were looking, as you said, was to find a "fireable" offense (a pretext). Do you really think that if someone tipped off HR out of the blue about this, they would proceed "automatically" with termination?

Comment: @teego1967 that's what I've been told.  Having never worked there I've not actually read their employee handbook/etc.

Answer (score -2):

The answers thus far are needlessly harsh.

Of course, it would have been better to just state that employer-B didn't work out. It happens sometimes. You want to leave your current job and then jump to a new employer and the job isn't what you expected or it's a bad fit for you. Most people can understand and sympathize with such an experience as long as it doesn't happen on a regular basis.

At this point you might be able to tell them that your employment with A ended a few months earlier and that, actually, you were at B and it didn't work out and you were embarrassed about it. That's a perfectly fine human dilemma, you don't have to over-apologize or use the word "lie".

Comment: The answers are harsh because most employment situations are harsh. In this case, the OP lied. In many environments, that is an automatic firing offense. Yes, that is harsh, but that is reality.

Comment: The intention behind "a lie" along with it's scope determines, to to a large extent, whether or not the lie is forgivable. How the OP handles "coming clean" will be important here.

Comment: Thanks guys. I declined the job offer for now to avoid getting caught during background check/ after joining. another condition of job letter that they want right to continue background check even after joining date incase BC is not completed by joining date. in that case i would be in trouble if BC finishes after joining new company and terminates employment based on discrepancy.